# Code to make div appear after a certain amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for code that makes a div appear after a certain amount of time on a site. Here's the sort of thing I'm talking about:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="secretpopout">
This is the div I want to pop out after a couple of minutes.
</div>
</div>
```

I'm relatively new to javascript and jQuery, but I'm assuming I will need to use the setTimeout or something similar. I've tried finding the answer online, but if someone could explain it in a way a designer (as opposed to a programmer) would get it, that would be great - ANY LIGHT shed on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with very little code in jQuery 1.4+ using [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".secretpopout").delay(120000).fadeIn();
});
```

This would show it after 2 minutes, just give it some CSS so it's hidden initially:

```
.secretpopout { display: none; }
```

Comment: Nice solution Nick....when I saw the question I was thinking of setTimeout....Pretty slick usage of delay.