# How to detect browser not minimized and relevant tab is not inactive

Tags: javascript, html, browser

In my website, there is a download page. I want to keep wait my users 15 seconds in download page. and i want to add 15 s timer before download button appear. Mean while if user click another tab in browser or minimize the browser, timer should stop.

My question is how to detect user is keep watching on web page which mean browser not minimized and this tab is not inactive. How to do this task in `javascript`.

Comment: In this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567832/code-to-make-div-appear-after-a-certain-amount-of-time  you can learn how to show your button after x seconds using jQuery delay.

Comment: @OmidHezaveh i just want to detect tab is active and browser not minimized.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but visibility API might help you to detect if the element is in view, or in focus https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

Comment: Page visibility API works for me.

Comment: Found more tutorials here http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/

Comment: Good to hear that, maybe I put those together to make an answer for others!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here a ready-to-use js

```
(function() {
    var hidden, visibilityChange;
    if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") { 
        hidden = "hidden";
        visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
    } else if (typeof document.mozHidden !== "undefined") {
        hidden = "mozHidden";
        visibilityChange = "mozvisibilitychange";
    } else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
        hidden = "msHidden";
        visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
    } else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
        hidden = "webkitHidden";
        visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
    }


    // If the page is hidden, pause the countdown;
    // if the page is shown, resume the countdown
    function handleVisibilityChange() {
        if (document[hidden]) {

            //pause your countdown
        } else {

            //resume your countdown
        }
    }

    // Warn if the browser doesn't support addEventListener or the Page Visibility API
    if (typeof document.addEventListener === "undefined" ||
        typeof document[hidden] === "undefined") {} else {
        // Handle page visibility change   
        document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false);

    }
})();
```

Hope this can help you! :)